# intellij shortcuts

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

ctrl+shift+ (left/right arrows)  (undo,redo) stopped working for me. 
It used to be accurate but now I cant predict where it will take me. 
It happened before, then got fixed,  but now it looks like it is jumping to weird places. 
cant make a sense out of it.

Same goes for the f4 in the form editor. it use to take me to declaration of the component in the code the but now it only puts me in the top of the class. 
10x

Comment: You may want to submit a bug: http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=IDEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the list of the known issues with the back/forward functionality:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-63218
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-64656
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-65070
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-63748
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-63082

Comment: All issue above are fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You might to check if you have accidentally switched the keymap. You can check it by following these steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>
- switch keymap
- choose "default copy"

Answer (score -1):

One reason for this can be accidentally changed of keymap. If that is the case, we can change it to default. Follow below step for that.

Open Setting (`Ctrl + Alt + s` or **File -> Settings**) then select keymap from left side bar. Then select **Restore Defaults** like below image.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Keymap]

If your **Restore Defaults** is gray colored like me, then your keymap in the default state, which means nothing is changed. If not there is change.